# How can I display product attribute in order summary in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, sales-order, magento2.2.3

I am trying to display weight of the products in the order summary like I have shown in the below screenshot. Anyone who knows help me out.
[image]

Comment: can you try this http://www.blogtreat.com/magento-2-display-custom-product-attribute-checkout-summary/

Comment: This one i have already seen...it will add the content below order total...please compare the output of mine and that one

Comment: have you find solution for this if you have please share to me thanks

Comment: no ..i didnt get solution